# Detect the device file used by a terminal

Tags: unix, terminal

When a terminal or console is started a `/dev/ttyX` file is created for that instance. From that given terminal, is it possible to detect through a command what is the `ttyX` file being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're looking for is a command, it's `tty`.

Answer (score 2):

You want `ttyname(3)`, which is POSIX-standard.

Comment: You sometimes have to be careful when using ttyname when redirecting the streams; `ttyname(0)` works fine until you redirect stdin when it suddenly segfaults.

Comment: Only if you're not checking for a `NULL` return from `ttyname`. Alternatively, you can always try `isatty` first.

Comment: Fair point.  I must have had a printf wrapper or something and misremembered.

Comment: What meaning has the `(0)`, is there a section 0 of the manual? Also is any of these can be actually used directly on the terminal?

Comment: I was using `ttyname(3)` in the sense of manual section 3. @dwarduk was talking about sending FD number 3 to `ttyname`. What do you mean by "directly on the terminal"? `ttyname` takes an FD, so you'd want something like `ttyname(stdin)`.

Comment: Directly in the terminal in the sense that it is available as a user command. Say like if there was a `ttyname(1)` (User commands section).

Comment: @chrylis: `stdin` is a `FILE *`, not a file descriptor. `0` is the file descriptor corresponding to standard input.